# Pass shell/bash commands to docker

Tags: bash, docker-compose, sh

I want to be able to set up an alias to run docker, and then run `composer install`.

This is my `sh` file:

```
cd ~/Documents/laradock/
docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
cd site
composer install
```

However once it has loaded docker and entered into it: `docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash` nothing happens

I am expecting to see:

```
cd site
composer install
```

but it doesn't pass these commands through.

Comment: You possibly need to background the `docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash` line as `bash` will never complete.  Try sticking an `&` on the end of that line.

Comment: Starting a new shell does not make subsequent commands in your script go to that shell. Your script *blocks* until the `docker-compose` command exits.

Comment: Try this at a command line: `bash; echo "after shell"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
docker-compose exec --user=laradock -T workspace bash << EOF
cd site
composer install
EOF
```